# I have a code which will limit the user to select max quantity available in store. But I want to notify the customer as well. How would i do that?

Tags: woocommerce

I have a code in my functions.php which will limit the user to select max quantity available in stock for each product. But i want to notify the customer as well that "Entered quantity exceeds stock available". How would i show this message to the customer when enters more than the stock quantity available.?

I have tried adding different codes in it but nothing worked. Really inexperience though in this field. so seeking you guys help.

add_action('woocommerce_add_to_cart', 'add_to_cart_qty', 10, 6 );
function add_to_cart_qty( $cart_item_key, $product_id, $quantity, $variation_id, $variation, $cart_item_data ){

```
$real_product_id = $variation_id > 0 ? $variation_id : $product_id;

$product = wc_get_product($real_product_id);
$product_stock = $product->get_stock_quantity();

if( $quantity > $product_stock && $product->get_manage_stock() ){
    WC()->cart->set_quantity( $cart_item_key, $product_stock );
}
```

The code above limits the user but does not show any notices to users.

Comment: please check [here](https://www.tychesoftwares.com/how-to-set-minimum-and-maximum-allowable-product-quantities-to-be-added-in-woocommerce-cart/) It can help you.

Comment: thanks but it wasn't that helpful